# ERROR failed to turn code into token

Tags: spring, https, jwt, firewall, keycloak

My spring web application throws an error, when receiving a token from keycloak. Keycloak and the spring web application are behind a firewall (FV). The protocol between client and firewall as well as between firewall and Keycloak / spring web application is https.

The jwt token set by keyclok is missing the fields "jti", "iat", and "exp". I cannot find any reason for these missing fields.

The spring web application throws the following exception:

```
2018-01-18 13:38:45,502 (http-nio-18092-exec-8               OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:340 ) ERROR failed to turn code into token
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:158) ~[httpcore-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
  at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82) ~[httpcore-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:271) ~[httpcore-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
  at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281) ~[httpcore-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:230) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.6.jar:4.4.6]
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
  at org.keycloak.adapters.ServerRequest.invokeAccessCodeToToken(ServerRequest.java:111) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.2.1.Final.jar:3.2.1.Final]
  at org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.resolveCode(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:330) [keycloak-adapter-core-3.2.1.Final.jar:3.2.1.Final]
  at org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthRequestAuthenticator.java:275) [keycloak-adapter-core-3.2.1.Final.jar:3.2.1.Final]
  at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:139) [keycloak-adapter-core-3.2.1.Final.jar:3.2.1.Final]
  at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.j
  at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:141) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.2.1.Final.jar:3.2.1.Final]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84) [keycloak-spring-security-adapter-3.2.1.Final.jar:3.2.1.Final]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.57]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

Any help? Thanx

Answer (score 3):

So it appears that you're using the [authorization code flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1), in which you receive a **code** via your browser, present it to the application server, and then the app server makes a **back channel** call to exchange the code for a token.  Remember, this is a multi-step process:

1. get a **code** (I.E. 94fe1f6b-c446-4c60-8641-e224e3613beb) from
   the Identity Provider - in this case Keycloak
2. present the **code** to the application (RP) via the browser
3. the application then exchanges the **code** for token(s)

Step #3 is what appears to be failing here.  I'd check the ability of your application to call the IDP directly.  Do things like ssh into the app node(s) and attempt to curl the token endpoint on the IDP.  Should be pretty straightfoward network type troubleshooting from there.